# Can't align bootstrap navbar links all the way to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Navbar link items don't go all the way up to the right when aligning them (using mr-auto), it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxiZQ.png)

And there's my html template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You would have to set the _left_ margin of that `ul` to auto, not the right one. (Only I can't make `ml-auto` work either, when I add your code in a jsfiddle, and add the BS5 stylesheet - doesn't look like that applies any styles. `m-auto` seems to exist, but that obviously doesn't do what you want here. Not sure if `ml-auto` is implemented correctly, the documentation appears to suggest that that _should_ be working.)

Comment: Bootstrap 5 [renamed several utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#utilities-3) to use logical property names instead of directional names. Therefore, left and right is now start and end. Try `ms-auto` or `me-auto`

Comment: Thanks, my navbar looks like I want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2 ">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Replace **mr-auto** with **ms-auto** so the text will appear on the right side.